# What did Coq 8.15 change about divmod?

Tags: coq, arithmetic

I noticed that Coq 8.15 (possibly 8.14) made some significant changes to divmod. In particular, `Nat.divmod_0q0` seems to have been removed and the `div_mod` lemma with signature `y<>0 -> x = y*(x/y) + x mod y` has effectively been replaced with `div_mod_eq` which drops the `y<>0` precondition.

Does `divmod` (and hence `div` and `mod`) now behave differently? Could somebody summarize the changes? It looks like some 8.15 theorems simply don't hold in 8.13 and vice-versa (with `Nat.divmod_0q0`).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This was changed in Coq 8.14 (MR: https://github.com/coq/coq/pull/14086), and the changes are summarized in https://coq.inria.fr/refman/changes.html#id310. Quoting:

> Changed: set `n mod 0 = n` uniformly for `nat`, `N`, `Z`, `int63`, `sint63`, `int31` such that `m = (m / n) * n + (m mod n)` holds (also for `n = 0`)

As you can see, in many cases this gives stronger theorems with fewer side conditions — but in any case they're more uniform across `nat`, `N` and `Z`.